# Min function not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I've searched and can't find a solution to my problem.

It seems simple.

I'm using SQL Server 2014, the table date column is defined as a varchar and is formatted as 'YYYYDDMM'.  The results still give me multiple dates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code

```
SELECT Part,
  CASE WHEN CreateDate= '00000000'
    THEN ''
    ELSE MIN(CreateDate)
  END 
as OrderDate
INTO #Ord
FROM POtbl, #PrtNoOrd WHERE part = partno AND PO like '4%'
GROUP BY Part, CreateDate
ORDER BY Part asc
```

The results

```
Part            OrderDate 
-01-123456-01   20151211
-01-123456-01   20151210
-01-123456-01   20150306
-02-276161-01   20150916
```

Comment: You group by 2 columns thats why the date repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Part,
   min(CASE WHEN CreateDate= '00000000'
    THEN ''
    ELSE CreateDate
    END) 
as OrderDate
INTO #Ord
FROM POtbl, #PrtNoOrd WHERE part = partno AND PO like '4%'
GROUP BY Part
ORDER BY Part asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Part,
  CASE WHEN CreateDate= '00000000'
    THEN ''
    ELSE CreateDate
  END 
as OrderDate
INTO #Ord
FROM POtbl, #PrtNoOrd WHERE part = partno AND PO like '4%'
GROUP BY Part -- , CreateDate
ORDER BY Part asc
```

Comment: you can't reference `createdate` non aggregated as you are doing.